# Boto3 presigned URL for download and upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Creating a presigned URL with boto3 is easy. There are docs such as this:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html

But these only allow for upload OR download. Can both be done at the same time?

With STS upload and download credentials can be created that allow both get and put, but is this possible with presigned URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible because the HTTP verb is part of the [canonical request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) which gets signed by the AWS credentials.